# PIC24F16KA101 RA4 pin not functioning as output

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am trying to use RA4 pin of PIC24F16KA101 as digital output.It is connected to one of the segments of the 7-segment display. But it is always giving a constant voltage of about 800mv. I am not able to drive this pin.

I checked the datasheet to know if it is an open drain, but that is not mentioned in the datasheet. I also tried setting it as open drain (ODCAbits.ODA4 = 1), and used a pull up resistor of 10K to Vcc(Vcc=3V). But still unable to drive it.

Does anyone faced such a problem?Any help is appreciated.....

Answer (score 2):

If a GPIO isn't working on a PIC then it is often because one of the peripherals is using it.  Many of the pins are multi purpose and if one of the peripherals is using it then it will not work as a GPIO.

The data sheet has this for the pin on the pinout diagram (for the PDIP20 package, double check for whichever package you are using):

PGC3/SOSCO/T1CK/U2CTS/CN0/RA4

This tells you which peripherals use the pin.  It means you need to figure out what PGC3 is for, and turn that off.  Then you have to work out what SOSCO is, and turn that off too.  Also T1CK (timer 1 clock input maybe?), U2CTS and CN0 have to be off.

Comment: Hai,
Thank you for the reply.
Actually it is multiplexed with these ,PGC3/SOSCO/T1CK/U2CTS/CN0/RA4, but I am not using any of these peripherlals. I've checked the registers of these peripherals and they all are disabled.
I am using PGC2 for debugging, and I've disconnected all external hardware devices from this port, and also checked for short.

Still this pin is giving around 800mv.

Comment: What are you measuring your 800mV with?  A scope or a DVM?  Could it be a signal which is oscillating?  Also which clock mode are you using? and what are you writing to which registers to disable the peripherals?  Lastly, have you tried lifting the pin (i.e completely disconnecting it from the circuit?) and seeing if it is still at 0.8v?

Comment: I'm measuring it with a DSO.It is a constant voltage.I've checked SOSCEN bit in OSCCON reg,No external clock for Timer1,Uart and CN0 are not enabled. I've already tried disconnecting the external hardware from this pin,but same result

Comment: What about PGC3?  What does that relate to?  If the pin isn't connected to anything and it's at 0.8v it has to be either (1)register settings or (2) the pin is input only (check datasheet) or (3) the PIC is broken.  It is hardly ever (3) but it can happen.  I can double check your register settings if you post them

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem with a PIC24FV32KA301.  The list of peripherals on this pin for my device is almost exactly the same as yours, namely:  PGEC3/SOSCO/SCLKI/U2CTS/CN0/RA4

The problem was in the SOSCSRC fuse of the FOSCSEL configuration word, which switches between, according to the data sheet: 
"analog crystal function" and "digital SCLKI function" on the SOSCO pin.

To get digital I/O on the SOCSO pin, the SOSCSRC fuse needed to be cleared.  By default it is set (1).  Here is the configuration line I used that did the trick:

```
_FOSCSEL( SOSCSRC_DIG );
```

The datasheet doesn't explicitly say this will permit digital I/O on the SOSCO pin, but I found in a [microchip forum post](http://picforum.ric323.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=71#p361) that the datasheet for a different device with a similar set of peripherals makes the situation more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is because probably Second Oscillator (SOSC) is enabled, you can disable it from bit SOSCEN in OSCCON register; the code would be:

OSCCONbits.SOSCEN = 0;

Then you can configure your pin as output with TRIS register as usual...

Answer (score 0):

Note the SOSC pins might be general purpose input pins (if not used as secondary oscillator), so you might not be able to use it as output pin